# Bootstrap progress bar missing style option

Tags: 8, theming

Drupal 8 using Bootstrap theme. I am trying to create a progress bar on my form. I have done it in a block with no problem but in the form it loses the "style" option and displays a blank progress bar.

I put in this:

```
    $form['pr_bar'] = [
        '#markup' => '<div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
          aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
            40% Complete (success)
          </div>
        </div>',
    ];
```

and get a blank bar. When i inspect element:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span></div>
</div>
```

Why is the style option missing and is this causing the blank bar?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how screen reader text relates to my issue, can you please explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#markup` filters the style option because of the xss filter.

Use an inline template instead:

```
$form['pr_bar'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => '
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ complete }}"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{ complete }}%">
        {{ complete }}% Complete (success)
      </div>
    </div>',
  '#context' => [
    'complete' => '40',
  ],
];
```

You can pass the percentage value as twig variable.